# vcbuild doesn't work - cannot determine current version of Node.js - building node repo on windows

Tags: python, node.js, windows, github

I would really love for some help. I've cloned the Node.js repo and I have activated the Boxstarter script.
https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/BUILDING.md#windows

[image]

Then I open the cmd and write:

```
.\vcbuild openssl-no-asm
```

I get this message:

```
Looking for Python
Python found in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\\python.exe
Cannot determine current version of Node.js
```

Comment: Seems like the code which prints this error is [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/41c1e72b761ea70b0b4b8407702d831586cba321/vcbuild.bat#L695), and it calls an external script [tools/getnodeversion.py](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/tools/getnodeversion.py). I suggest to run this script and see what output you get.

Comment: That's weird - the output is: 15.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I reran all the commands again and it worked, though other problems followed.

I wanna thank @urish for also suggesting the WSL - I recommend working on the WSL (**Windows Subsystem for Linux**) with VSCode :) https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl
It works (almost) perfectly!

(of course you could also use a virtual machine).